# Using global time.sleep() leads to invalid Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, global

```
def imports():

    import time
    global time.sleep()


def title_screen():

    print("Welcome to Text RPG")
    print("Created by: Nick Giesler")
    print("")
    input("Press ENTER to Begin:")
    print("Loading...")
    time.sleep(1)


imports()

title_screen()
```

When ran, this returns invalid syntax pointing to "`global time.sleep()`":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "python", line 3    
    global time.sleep()
              ^    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What did you think `global time.sleep()` was supposed to do? That's nothing like how either `global` or `time.sleep` are supposed to be used.

Comment: What is the question, again?

Comment: You don't need a function for the import calls. Those are meant to be at the top of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Only `identifier`(s) can follow [the global statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

> `global_stmt ::=  "global" identifier ("," identifier)*`

where identifiers are plain names such as:

```
a = 20
b = "string" 
global a, b
```

when you break that requirement and python isn't able to find an identifier after `global`, a `SyntaxError` is going to get raised.

What you've entered after the `global` keyword isn't an identifier; it's [a function call](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) which is syntactically recognized by the `()` after the identifier.